# ralink 148f:760b mt7601 driver kernel panic on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers

New wireless network card in  can't drive

```
Bus 001 Device 005:ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

I downloaded the MT7601U driver *DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913.tar.bz2* from Mediatek website compile properly after installing driver to connect to a wireless network.
But once the Web page is open system just crashed.
Dmesg in panic before I got problem solved find hope

```
[  645.883776] skbuff: skb_over_panic: text:ffffffff815e5e3b len:1570 put:130 head:ffff8800c93d8f80 data:ffff8800c93d9024 tail:0xc93d9646 end:0x680 dev:<NULL>
[  645.883819] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  645.883854] kernel BUG at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.44/net/core/skbuff.c:126!
[  645.883889] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP 
[  645.883917] Modules linked in: rndis_host cdc_ether usbnet mii cfg80211 rfcomm bnep bluetooth mt7601Usta(OF) coretemp kvm_intel kvm hid_generic gpio_ich ppdev usbhid hid snd_hda_codec_via snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc lpc_ich snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event microcode psmouse serio_raw snd_rawmidi nouveau snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer mxm_wmi parport_pc wmi video ttm drm_kms_helper snd drm mac_hid i2c_algo_bit soundcore lp parport atl1c
[  645.884233] CPU: 0 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Tainted: GFO 3.13.44-generic #31-Ubuntu
[  645.884274] Hardware name: MSI MS-7592/G41TM-P31 (MS-7592), BIOS V1.14 05/18/2011
[  645.884311] task: ffffffff81c15440 ti: ffffffff81c00000 task.ti: ffffffff81c00000
[  645.884348] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff816e9f1d>]  [<ffffffff816e9f1d>] skb_panic+0x63/0x65
[  645.884393] RSP: 0018:ffff88012fc03b18  EFLAGS: 00010286
[  645.884420] RAX: 000000000000008f RBX: ffff8800c91cb000 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  645.884456] RDX: 00000000000400f6 RSI: ffff88012fc0e428 RDI: 0000000000000246
[  645.884491] RBP: ffff88012fc03b38 R08: 000000000000000a R09: 0000000000001590
[  645.884526] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: ffff88012fc0383e R12: ffff8800c91cb100
[  645.884561] R13: 0000000000000082 R14: ffff88012fc03ba4 R15: 0000000000000014
[  645.884596] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88012fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  645.884637] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
[  645.884665] CR2: 00007f3bf64b2019 CR3: 00000000c6bf9000 CR4: 00000000000407f0
[  645.884700] Stack:
[  645.884712]  ffff8800c93d9024 00000000c93d9646 0000000000000680 ffffffff81a74a6f
[  645.884756]  ffff88012fc03b48 ffffffff815e2578 ffff88012fc03b90 ffffffff815e5e3b
[  645.884801]  ffffffff815e176b 0000000100000000 ffff88010dfd5100 ffff8800c91cb000
[  645.884845] Call Trace:
[  645.884859]  <IRQ> 
[  645.884871]  [<ffffffff815e2578>] skb_put+0x48/0x50
[  645.884905]  [<ffffffff815e5e3b>] skb_try_coalesce+0xbb/0x400
[  645.884935]  [<ffffffff815e176b>] ? skb_checksum+0x5b/0x2f0
[  645.884966]  [<ffffffff81637fed>] tcp_try_coalesce.part.40+0x2d/0x90
[  645.884999]  [<ffffffff81638fd8>] tcp_queue_rcv+0xf8/0x130
[  645.885029]  [<ffffffff8163e284>] tcp_rcv_established+0x314/0x670
[  645.885062]  [<ffffffff81648155>] tcp_v4_do_rcv+0x1b5/0x470
[  645.885092]  [<ffffffff810f9882>] ? handle_fasteoi_irq+0x72/0x100
[  645.885124]  [<ffffffff8164a327>] tcp_v4_rcv+0x777/0x790
[  645.885153]  [<ffffffff816eee2d>] ? common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[  645.885185]  [<ffffffff816259e4>] ip_local_deliver_finish+0xb4/0x1f0
[  645.885219]  [<ffffffff81625cb8>] ip_local_deliver+0x48/0x80
[  645.885248]  [<ffffffff81625689>] ip_rcv_finish+0x79/0x320
[  645.885278]  [<ffffffff81625f24>] ip_rcv+0x234/0x370
[  645.885306]  [<ffffffff815f1506>] __netif_receive_skb_core+0x646/0x830
[  645.885339]  [<ffffffff815f1708>] __netif_receive_skb+0x18/0x60
[  645.885370]  [<ffffffff815f220d>] process_backlog+0xad/0x1a0
[  645.885399]  [<ffffffff815f1aac>] net_rx_action+0x11c/0x230
[  645.885430]  [<ffffffff81067457>] __do_softirq+0xf7/0x240
[  645.885459]  [<ffffffff816f8edc>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[  645.885489]  [<ffffffff81014bf5>] do_softirq+0x55/0x90
[  645.885516]  [<ffffffff81067735>] irq_exit+0xb5/0xc0
[  645.885543]  [<ffffffff816f97d6>] do_IRQ+0x56/0xc0
[  645.885569]  [<ffffffff816eee2d>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[  645.885597]  <EOI> 
[  645.885609]  [<ffffffff8104d386>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
[  645.885646]  [<ffffffff8101b24f>] default_idle+0x1f/0xc0
[  645.885675]  [<ffffffff8101bb16>] arch_cpu_idle+0x26/0x30
[  645.885705]  [<ffffffff810b5805>] cpu_startup_entry+0xe5/0x280
[  645.885737]  [<ffffffff816d67a7>] rest_init+0x77/0x80
[  645.885765]  [<ffffffff81d26ef7>] start_kernel+0x40a/0x416
[  645.887118]  [<ffffffff81d268f6>] ? repair_env_string+0x5c/0x5c
[  645.887738]  [<ffffffff81d26120>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x120/0x120
[  645.887738]  [<ffffffff81d265de>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x2a/0x2c
[  645.887738]  [<ffffffff81d266e8>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x108/0x117
[  645.887738] Code: 00 00 48 89 44 24 10 8b 87 c8 00 00 00 48 89 44 24 08 48 8b 87 d8 00 00 00 48 c7 c7 98 81 ad 81 48 89 04 24 31 c0 e8 83 7c ff ff <0f> 0b 55 48 89 e5 0f 0b 55 48 89 e5 0f 0b 55 48 89 e5 0f 0b 66 
[  645.887738] RIP  [<ffffffff816e9f1d>] skb_panic+0x63/0x65
[  645.887738]  RSP <ffff88012fc03b18>
[  651.004092] MediaState is connected
[  651.004357] ==>rt_ioctl_giwmode(mode=2)
[  651.004609] ==>rt_ioctl_giwfreq  11
[  651.004879] rt28xx_get_wireless_stats --->
[  651.005156] <--- rt28xx_get_wireless_stats
```

---

Here is some information about wireless driver

**sudo lshw -numeric -class network**

```
*-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: ra0
       serial: 44:33:4c:2b:a5:14
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
```

**sudo iwlist scan**

```
ra0       Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 38:83:45:C8:53:30
                    Protocol:11b/g/n BW40
                    ESSID:"WiFi-Lyoko"
                    Mode:Managed
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=100/100  Signal level=-45 dBm  Noise level=-92 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:150 Mb/s
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Comment: "...compile properly..." Obviously not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you remove the faulty driver:

```
cd ~/Downloads/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913
sudo make uninstall
sudo modprobe -r mt7601Usta
```

Now, let's try a different driver:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git 
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo mkdir -p /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Please let us know if it works as expected.

You have compiled the driver for your currently running kernel version only. When Update Manager installs a later linux-image, after the requested reboot, re-compile:

```
cd mt7601/src
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Please retain the file and these instructions for that time.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, Linux kernel 3.19.0-28-generic

```
git clone https://github.com/porjo/mt7601.git
cd mt7601/src
make
checkinstall
dpkg -i *.deb
```